# Android Studio - Imprimir via spooler do Windows

Tags: android, windows, impressora

Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de enviar as impressões via spooler do windows. Estou fazendo um sitema de bares e como tem muitos apps conectados ao mesmo tempo na rede, se eu mandar imprimir diretamente na impressora, ao receber muitas requisições a impressora não responde devido ao timeout e consequentemente perco impressões. Imagina vc estar em um bar e fazer um pedido e ele não vir pq quando o garçon enviou seu pedido pelo app ele não imprimiu na impressora por ter muitas requisições. Pelo spooler do windows eu sei que existe um controle (fila) para impressões, evitando que a impressora não receba as requisições e consequentemente atrapalhando muito o cliente e o estabelecimento. Pesquisei por mais de uma semana na internet e não acho nada a respeito. Estou quase sendo despedido por não conseguir resolver o problema e muito preocupado com a situação. Alguém tem alguma ajuda?

Comment: Apenas pra lhe ajudar na pesquisa já que ninguém respondeu, você está utilizando qual tecnologia? [PrintManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintManager)?

Comment: Da uma olhada se [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742051/android-printmanager-get-callback) lhe ajuda.